# Reuired Field Validator Not working on Textbox Input

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Below shown `requiredFieldvalidtor` is not working. Although other fields are showing proper error messages. But their type is dropdown.
Code in `.aspx` File:

```
<td>
     <asp :TextBox runnat ='server' ID='spc'></asp :TextBox>
     <asp : RequiredFieldValidator ID ='aer' runnat='server' 
            controlToValidate='spc' ErrorMessage='Please enter the 
            required'InitialValue="0">
     </asp : Requiredfield>
</td>
```

Comment: where is the screen ?

Comment: Code in .aspx File :
<td>
<asp :TextBox runnat ='server' ID='spc'></asp : TextBox>
<asp : RequiredFieldValidator ID ='aer' runnat='server' controlToValidate='spc' ErrorMessage='Please enter the required' InitialValue="0"></asp : Requiredfield>
</td>

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). please do ***not*** put code in comments, it is utterly unreadable. ***edit*** your question to include the information, ***take care of proper formatting*** (preview before saving!), and most of all: provide a ***better error description*** than "is not working".

Comment: please check stackoverflow sharing guidelines

Comment: Certainly typo's, but runnat ='server' should be runat="server" (one n). Ending tag should be </asp:RequiredFieldValidator> not </asp : Requiredfield>

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
     <asp:TextBox runat ='server' ID='spc' />
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID ='aer' runat='server' controlToValidate='spc' ErrorMessage='Please enter the required' />
</td>
```